# Weird behavior with GET and POST

Tags: javascript, html, rest, post, get

I am trying to use a web service in iOS to replicate the functionality of this form. I am running into a problem though. Anytime I send a post to it, I get an error saying

```
<html><head>
<title>410 Gone</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Gone</h1>
/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsechas been permanently removed from this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

When I goto [this page](https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched?) and select Spring 2013, it takes me to [this page](https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckgens.p_proc_term_date). The problem is, the page 2 only loads if you went through page one to get there. How does the website know whether you went through there or not? I dug around and found it sends a POST request with the value p_calling_proc=bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched and p_term=201320(for spring 2013). When I send page2 this POST command I get the same results as if I just visited page 2 without visiting page 1: "/prod/bwckgens.p_proc_term_datehas been permanently removed from this server." I then thought I should behave more like a web browser and initially send a GET request to page one. When I receive a response, I should send a POST request with the aforementioned data filled in. When I do this, I still get the same error. Is there something I am not taking into account? All I want to do is send GET/POST requests so I can get a list of the classes being offered.

The second page basically sends a POST request to [this page](https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec) with the following variables:
term_in=201320&sel_subj=CS&sel_day=dummy&sel_schd=dummy&sel_insm=dummy&sel_camp=dummy&sel_levl=dummy&sel_sess=dummy&sel_instr=dummy&sel_ptrm=dummy&sel_attr=dummy

Can someone help me figure out how to replicate this behavior? I know very little about web development and feel like I am missing a key point here which is hindering me from finishing this app. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the first page sets a cookie that the second page checks.

Comment: A cookie is not part of the HTML. it's part of the HTTP header. If you look at the response headers (for example, in firebug, or with `curl -v 'https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched?'`) for the first page, you can see a cookie being set. It's impossible to know what the server does with that cookie without having access to the server-side code, but that's a typical usage of cookies.